# What is it called when the first/last note of a three-/four-note chord is moved one half-step up/down?

Tags: piano, chords

Is there a term for the chord or the act of moving the note?

There are a few songs I know of that do this, e.g., the last chord of The Platters’ Only You and Stranger Things’ theme.

Comment: I've listened to both of your examples and I'm not certain what you're referring to. Could you give us a video and timestamp by any chance?

Comment: Of course, @Richard. The examples I listed were terrible. Take, for example, a chord composed of E, G, B, and Eb — or a chord composed of A, Db, E, and Ab.

Comment: @Crys.... instead use `E G B` and `D#` or `A C# E` and `G#`...but we know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

This may not apply to the cases of interest to the original questioner but things like an A-minor chord moving to an F6 chord (A-C-E to A-C-F) is referred to the 5-6 technique. The technique also applies to whole tone movement. The procedure is reversible. One can do similar things with the lower note like (C-F-A to D-F-A). I don't really know a name for the procedure.

I think (but I'm not sure and I'm not familiar with the relevant literature) that some neo-Riemannian procedures follow this. There are placements of notes (or chords) on a hexagonal lattice (Tonnetz) which encompass these techniques.

Answer (score 1):

For the last chord of The Platters’ *Only You* I think you need to provide some music, because I don't see the half-step movement you mention.

In the *Stranger Things* theme I think you mean...

[image]

...where the circled notes are the half-step movement you mention.

I think the theme exploits a harmonic *ambiguity* and creates its effect from a few musical elements rather than one single device with a tidy name. So bear with my long-ish answer...

If we simply list out the notes used in the beginning and arrange them in thirds we get `C E G B` which at face value is `C` *major-seventh chord.* The bass note is `E` instead of `C` and so we say the chord is in *first inversion*...

[image]

...**if* we labeled the chord as such it would be `I6/3`.

If we use that chord label, the half-step movement would be called simply a *broken chord*, because the movement is using only the notes of the chord.

The problem with that analysis is the music really sounds like it's in a minor mode. A `C` major-seventh chord does not seem a good chord to represent the sound of a minor mode *tonic chord*. So I want another way to analyze this music.

Instead I can consider the `E` of the bass the chord root and the circled `E G B` are the chord tones for an `Em` chord.

This leaves out the `C` tones indicated by arrows.

We call these *non-chord tones* (NCT), because they don't "belong" to the `Em` chord. NCTs add *tension* to music. This "not fitting" the chord and tension can also be called *dissonance*. If a NCT moves to a chord tone, it is called *resolving*. So, the dissonance and tension of a NCT is resolved by moving the tone to a chord tone.

[image]

A few observations can be made from this view.

- `Em` certainly better matches the minor mode feel of the music.
- the upper `C` tone is part of a *neighboring motion* with the `B` or the `Em` chord. This is an example of a dissonant NCT resolving into a chord tone.
- the lower `C` does not involve a step-wise resolution to a chord tone. This tone is *implied* to be sustained through the whole measure. That is an implied, sustained, unresolved dissonance. This adds a lot of tension to the music. I think this constant tension creates an *angst* which expresses the mood of the t.v. show.
- it's reasonable to return to the first idea and call this a `C` major-seventh chord. That *possibility* makes the theme a bit ambiguous. In some settings a major-seventh chord sounds very mellow and pretty. I think this ambiguity tempers the strong dissonance of a minor second - which could be found in many horror movie soundtracks - to something less harsh, more *eerie* than terrifying.

On a purely technical note. The score samples above are from a YouTube video, they aren't a real score of the recorded theme. As recorded the `E` in the left-hand bass clef is a synth bass which is clearly lower than the `C` in the right-hand bass clef.

I threw out a bunch of music theory terms in this answer only to give you the details to understand *my* conclusion. I think the essential effect of the music is created by an *unresolved dissonant non-chord tone* and the half step movement from `B` to `C` would be called a *neighbor tone*.